# onWrite in Multiple Database in one Firebase Project

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase project which has one default database and 3 other databases which I have created. I understand that each of these database contain a different URL which can be used to trigger cloud functions.

All the 3 database have a path /ref/user/message. Now in my Index.JS file I want to create a function which performs onWrite if there's an update performed on the above path from any of the database. Also, I would want to know which database instance has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to write one function for each of the database instances, but you can pretty easily share common code between them by having them all call a common function.

```
exports.db1 = functions.database.instance('db1').ref('/your/path').onWrite((change,context) => {
    return onWrite('db1', change, context)
})

exports.db2 = functions.database.instance('db2').ref('/your/path').onWrite((change,context) => {
    return onWrite('db2', change, context)
})

function onWrite(instance, change, context) {
    // your code here
    return some_promise
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer? What is 'db1' and 'db2' and how's it declared, your answer seems to help me partially. Thanks.

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#specify_the_database_instance_and_path).  It's the unique name of you database instance.

Comment: When I try giving instance name then I am getting Deployment Error.
Details are;
Error Code: 13 and Reason: Internal, It would be really great if you could give a full example please.

Comment: I don't know what your instance names are, so I can't show you what to type.  The documentation I linked is the main point of reference.

Comment: Thank you for your support. The issue is resolved. I was not entering the config data properly.